# How to unpack this list comprehension

Tags: python

I got some lists of all integer.
If use this example `filter = [x for x in res if all(item in x for item in v_h) ]` it got the result as 3441.

If I unpack it like this:

```
f = []

for x in res:
    for item in v_h:
        if item in x:
            if all(x):
                f.append(x)
```

I get 39490, how do I unpack it correctly?

full code:

```
import time

start_time = time.time()

def make_comb(goal, nums):
    lists = [[num] for num in nums]
    new_lists = []
    collected = []
    while lists:
        for list in lists:
            s = sum(list)
            for num in nums:
                if num >= list[-1]:
                    if s + num < goal:
                        new_lists.append(list + [num])
                    elif s + num == goal:
                        collected.append(list + [num])
        lists = new_lists
        new_lists = []
    return collected



h = 240
v_h = [3,6,9,18,24]

sizes = []
[sizes.append(x) for x in v_h if x not in sizes]

res = make_comb(h, v_h)

filter = [x for x in res if all(item in x for item in v_h) ]

f = []

for x in res:
    for item in v_h:
        if item in x:
            if all(x):
                f.append(x)

# print(*filter, sep="\n")
print("--- %s valid combinations ---" % len(f))
print("--- %s valid combinations ---" % len(filter))
print("--- %s total combinations ---" % len(res))
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: show your list to get a grasp of what you are saying

Comment: just run script, there everything in it

Comment: what is your goal actually.There's a better way to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
filter = [x for x in res if all(item in x for item in v_h) ]
```

Is this:

```py
ret = []
for x in res:
    append = True
    for item in v_h:
        if item not in x:
            append = False
            break
    if append:
        ret.append(x)
```

Then you can check if it's `not in x` and set a flag whether or not to append `x`

Comment: Sir, this is great, the bottom line was that I did not check item in x, that is, if it is not there, then we stop running x, sir can you tell me how I should proceed in order to further solve such problems myself?

Comment: You need to think about what the functions are doing that you're using. In this case `all` in list comprehension is just making sure to add something if it meets that criteria. It's going to be different for every  situation so it's hard to give an answer that fits all cases. You could start by using the debugger to check when items are being added and if they should be or not.

Answer (score 2):

You have an unnecessary call to `all` in your unpacking. You can simulate `x` with a `for` loop with an `else` clause.

```
filter = []
for x in res:
    for item in v_h:
        if item not in x:
            break
    else:
        filter.append(x)
```

`x` will be added to `filter` if the inner loop completes without ever reaching the `break` statement, i.e., if `item not in x` is always false.

Keeping `all`,

```
filter = []
for x in res:
    if all(item in x for item in v_h):
        filter.append(x)
```

which can be seen to mirror the structure of the original list comprehension more closely.

Answer (score 1):

If my answer is wrong any criticism is welcome.

```
filter = []
for x in res:
    execute = True
    for item in v_h:
        if(item not in x):
            execute = False
            break;
    if(execute):
        filter.append(x)
```